# Using a PowerBI gateway with web data sources: query parameters

Tags: microsoft-powerbi

We have an onprem gateway for PowerBI that gives access to some SQL and Web datasources.

This is working, but it appears that each internal web address that we want to use in PowerBI has to be added as a separate data source, which is inconvenient.

All the data sources go through the same endpoint, with different parameters to control which backend report actually is executed.

Initially, I had set up a url `.../get.php?report=id` but I was only able to add one, as powerbi used get.php as the "unique" data source name behind the scenes and refused to let me add another one with a different id.

I then redesigned so that I had `.../get.php/id/params/report+name` which solved the initial issue, but I still have to have one data source per report defined in our gateway.

Is there no solution for this? Can I not just define a data source as `.../powerbi.php` and have powerbi pass query parameters either through a query string or even a post body?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my understanding that is "by design". Dumb design IMO. They have recently made a botched attempt to fix it:

https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/skip-test-connection-for-on-premises-and-cloud-data-sources/

I'm not certain this would apply to your scenario, but Chris Webb's blog posts seem the best resource on this topic:

https://blog.crossjoin.co.uk/2019/04/25/skip-test-connection-power-bi-refresh-failures/#comment-105465

Comment: It seems like `Web.Contents` with a Query argument will give me what I want then. As the api is under my control, I can easily make it so the connection test succeeds :) I will be testing this out as soon as I can.